# String.replace() Python remove first coincidence

Tags: python, replace

Following the Python documentation for string.replace, I'm trying to replace a string, such as "843845ab38".  How can I make a string.replace(old,new) only replacing the first coincidence?

example:

```
a="843845ab38"
a.replace("8","")
print a
```

The solution that I'm looking for is "43845ab38", replacing the first 8 by a space.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation. Please read it carefully before posting. http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) takes a 3rd argument, called count:

```
a.replace("8", "", 1)
```

By passing in `1` as the count only the *first* occurance of `'8'` is replaced:

```
>>> a = "843845ab38"
>>> a.replace("8", "", 1)
'43845ab38'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use replace function.
Just 
a[1:] will be enough
however if you want to replace all "8"s
then you may want to use replace

Comment: And how does he know that the first 8 is at position 0?

Comment: I guess user1350772 said something like this.. "The solution that I'm looking for is "43845ab38", replacing the first 8 by a space."

Comment: Yes, the first occurance of the digit 8. This doesn't mean that it occurs at position 0...